# Vega visualization - how to enable actions when using vega view

Tags: javascript, django, visualization, vega, vega-lite

I am using vega charts in my django project. Until now I have used the vegaEmbed to show chart's on web page but now I would like to switch to vega view and I can't found anywhere how to enable actions when using vega view.

This is my code with vegaEmbed:

```
    `<script>
      var {{ c.ident }} = {{ c.jSon|safe }}
          var {{ c.ident }}_opt = {
                  actions: true
                }
          vegaEmbed('#{{ c.ident }}', {{ c.ident }}, {{ c.ident }}_opt);
        vegaEmbed('#{{ c.ident }}', {{ c.ident }});
    </script>`
```

And this code with vega view:

```
        `<script>
            var vegaJson = {{ jSon|safe }};
            var view = new vega.View(vega.parse(vegaJson))
                    .renderer('svg')  
                    .initialize('#chartDiv') 
                    .hover()             
                    .run();

            window.onresize = function (event) {
              view.signal('width', event.target.innerWidth - 200)
                  .signal('height', event.target.innerHeight - 450)
                  .run('enter');
            }
        </script>`
```

Any idea how to enable actions when using vega view?

[image: actions in vegaEmbed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actions menu is not defined by the vega view API, it is defined within vega-embed.

[Here](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed/blob/ed326f48996dbb3c3fb8f0a4517f0523afa123be/src/embed.ts#L342-L437) is how vega-embed creates the actions menu.

If you want to avoid using Vega-Embed and you still want an actions menu similar to what Vega-Embed implements, you would have to write similar code in your vega view script.